# I would like to know Google's Website translator is free to consume in our website? Are there any other concerns to use it in our website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, plugins, google-translate, vs-web-site-project

I am currently trying to use google website translator plugin to my website. I get the below code to be placed in the page which requires conversion. I would like to know if this can be used for free and also please let me know Consequences of using google website translator?

`<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function googleTranslateElementInit() {
     new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en' }, 'google_translate_element'); }
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?b=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

Google has an article about attribution / usage rights for all of its products:

> Whenever you display translation results from Google Translate
>   directly to users, you must make it clear to users that they are
>   viewing automatic translations from Google Translate using the
>   appropriate text or brand elements.
>
> If unaltered translation results are displayed on web pages that can
>   be indexed by search engines, you are required to designate the
>   translated text as machine translated content using the HTML markup
>   reference.
>
> Google Translate service: Use only the term "Google Translate" to
>   refer to the service made available through these APIs and at URLs
>   such as http://translate.google.com. Do not modify this word mark, for
>   example, through hyphenation, combination abbreviation, or acronym
>   such as: Google-Translate, GT, GoogTrans, GTrans, etc.
>
> In addition to following Google's general Brand Features guidelines,
>   you are also required to adopt certain branding elements when using
>   the Cloud Translation API. These forms of attribution are used in
>   order to maintain consistency and preserve the Google brand identity.
>
> The following basic principles govern use of the Google name and logo
>   in conjunction with the Cloud Translation API:
>
> Google attribution is required. The Google name and logo should be
>   associated with Google Translate only. The Google logo may never
>   appear next to or on the same page with the logos of competing web or
>   other search services. There are no exceptions to this rule. The
>   "powered by Google Translate" graphic must always be displayed
>   adjacent any translation results. You shall display any and all
>   intellectual property rights legends and notices (e.g., copyright
>   notices) as instructed by Google. Translation results Your application
>   may display, in response to a user’s action, translation results
>   obtained from the Cloud Translation API. Whenever you display such
>   information, you must include attribution to Google using one of the
>   badges below. Attribution badges on web pages must link to
>   http://translate.google.com. You can download a zip file of the badges
>   here.
>
> The version of the attribution using the full-color Google logo is
>   preferred, but depending on your application or website’s layout and
>   color-scheme, you must use one of these visual attribution styles:

The citations above are the parts relevant to this question, a full and up-to-date description can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution

Comment: By Looking at my code chunk, Am not too sure if am using Cloud Translation API?  If you see my code, It doesn't use any piece of identification.. how will they do pricing?

Comment: Where do you see anything with pricing? To my best knowledge the service is free, you can find the necessary attributions needed to use the service on the link above.